# How to plot a scatterplot using numbers in core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I need to draw a scatter plot with the given array of numbers in iPhone. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of help exactly you require?

Comment: actually am retriving some values and storing them in a mutable array.Now i need to draw a scatterplot with that retrived values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to write a method which will returns an object of `(NSNumber *)` and takes NSInteger (it will be the index for which you want the value) as parameter. Inside this method you will retrieve the value from a specific index of your `NSMutableArray`.

Now step number 2) write the method as shown below. By this method the graph will know how many co - ordinates are to be plotted.

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot {
    return (here you should call your method that will return the length of your array);
}
```

Step 3) This is the method to which your graph will look at for plotting a coordinate.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)
    {
        return (value that you want to plot on X- axis. for example index);
    }
    else
    {
        return ( call your method you implemented in step 1) that will fetch a value from your array and pass (index) as parameter); // It will plot the value on the y-axis.
    }
}
```